# spark sql Update one column in a delta table on silver layer

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I have a look up table which looks like below attached screenshot.
[image]

and the delta table is as below
[image]

here as you can see materialnum for all in the silver table is set as null which i am trying to update from the look up table based on SERIALNUM. In my project this is a requirement to load historical data. so i am trying with MERGE statemet.

```py
spark.sql(f"""MERGE INTO dev.supplychange_silver.ael_events_supply_change_test USING 
  (SELECT * FROM supply_change1) latestChange ON latestChange.SERIALNUM = dev.supplychange_silver.ael_events_supply_change_test.SERIALNUM 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dev.supplychange_silver.ael_events_supply_change_test.materialnum = latestChange.MATERIALNUM 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED and 1=2 THEN INSERT *""")
```

my only intention is to update the materialnum filed when matched.
But this is throwing me the below error.

```
> AnalysisException: cannot resolve S3_FILE_LOCATION in INSERT clause
> given columns latestChange.SERIALNUM, latestChange.MATERIALNUM; line 1
> pos 0
```

can someone tell me is MERGE not possible in this scenario or the only option here to load historical data is via left outer join.

Comment: why not simply omit the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause as it was proposed in answer for your previous question